# Search Excel file for 2 strings, copy, and paste to new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, search

I'm new to VBA and trying to write a code where it searches an Excel sheet for a string. When it finds it (start position), searches for another string and finds it (end position) copy all the rows in-between those two and copy them to a new sheet.

Each row being copied has 3 columns as well that need to be copy/pasted with it.

I've tried modifying some codes on here and some from YouTube but haven't had any luck. This is the code I have so far. Thanks for any help you can offer

```
Employee = Sheet1.Cells(5, 1)
TTI = Sheet1.Cells(3, 1)
Dim rng As Range
Dim Employee As String
Dim rownumber As Long

Set rng = Sheet1.Columns("A:A").Find(What:=Employee, _
    LookIn:=x1Formulas, LookAt:=x1Whole, SearchOrder:=x1byRows, _
    SearchDirection:=x1Next, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    rownumber = rng.Row
    rng = Sheet1.Columns("rownumber,A:A").Find(What:=TTI, _
    LookIn:=x1Formulas, LookAt:=x1Whole, SearchOrder:=x1byRows, _
    SearchDirection:=x1Next, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    rownumber2 = rng.Row

Sheet2.Cells(2, 1).String = Sheet.Cells("rownumber, 1:rownumber2, 1").String
```

When I try to run the code all I get is a runtime error

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53286864/edit) adding what code you have so far and how it fails to accomplish your desired goal?

Comment: Added the code, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below as a template for your macro, some ranges might need to be adjusted to suit your needs.

```
Sub test()

    Dim iRowStart As Integer, iRowEnd As Integer, iCol As Integer

    iCol = 7

    iRowEnd = FindString("To", iCol)
    iRowStart = FindString("From", iCol)


    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(iRowStart, iCol), Cells(iRowEnd, iCol)).Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A2")
    ActiveSheet.Cells(iRowStart, 1).Select

End Sub


Function FindString(str As String, iCol As Integer) As Integer
    Dim c As Range
    Dim rSearch As Range

    Set rSearch = ActiveSheet.Columns(iCol)

    With rSearch
        Set c = .Find(str, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            FindString = c.Row
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: I changed the range and the strings that the code is looking for but it can't find them despite them being in the column. From searching on here it looks like cell format can cause this problem but I can't find how to change it.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Try now, you have to make sure you correctly define both strings and the column containing them.  Cheers,